# regex list for scrapy deny rules

Tags: python, scrapy

this drives me mad, as I seem too dumb to be able to give scrapy a list of regex structures which the crawler should use in a deny rule.

I try to filter out all my project URLs which contain the word(parts) "top", "kredit" and "versicherung" (and will try to add even more URL parts as filter criteria). I tried with the folowing structure:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=r'versicher',
                             r='top',
                             r'kredit',),
          callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

However, this results in a syntax error (using deny=r'versicher'), alone works).

I haven't found any help for dummy beginners in the documentation or in the online examples, so maybe someone can help me here?

This is the spider:

```
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import NorisbankItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class NorisbankSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "nbtest"
allowed_domains = ['norisbank.de']
start_urls = ['https://www.norisbank.de']
custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "norisbank_%(time)s.json",
                  'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
                  }
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
       filename='nbtest.log',
       format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
       level=logging.INFO
                   )
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=[r'versicher',
                                  r'kredit']),
              callback='parse_norisbank', follow=True)],

def parse_norisbank(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'nbtest-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

    #Content Extraction
    print(response.url)

    l = ItemLoader(NorisbankItem(), response=response)

    l.add_xpath('sitename', "//meta[@property='og:site_name']/@content")
    l.add_xpath('siteurl', "//link[@rel='canonical']/@href")
    l.add_xpath('dbCategory',"//meta[@name='dbCategory']/@content")
    l.add_css('title','title::text')
    l.add_xpath('descriptions',"normalize-space(//meta[@name='description']/@content)")
    l.add_xpath('date',"//meta[@name='date']/@content")
    l.add_xpath('version',"//meta[@name='v']/@content")
    l.add_xpath('time',"//meta[@name='time']/@content")
    l.add_xpath('sitecontent','//body//p//text()')
    yield l.load_item()

    all_pages = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "html")]/@href').getall()
    for next_page in all_pages :
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

And this the log output:

```
2020-07-17 13:58:30 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2020-07-17 13:58:30 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
_inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 143, in from_crawler
spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 49, in from_crawler
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 79, in __init__
self._compile_rules()
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 139, in _compile_rules
self._rules[-1]._compile(self)
builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_compile'
2020-07-17 13:58:30 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 143, in from_crawler
spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 49, in from_crawler
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 79, in __init__
self._compile_rules()
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 139, in _compile_rules
self._rules[-1]._compile(self)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_compile'
2020-07-17 13:58:30 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 143, in from_crawler
spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 49, in from_crawler
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 79, in __init__
self._compile_rules()
File "/export/home/search/app/venv_p36_scrapy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 139, in _compile_rules
self._rules[-1]._compile(self)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_compile'
```

I've put the code in a traceback block, however, no other information as in the output log was obtained. As I'm very new to this, perhaps you can help me how to obtain more usefull information? I've put my traceback block here for review. I'm very sorry for my dumb questions, but I'm an absolut beginner with Python and Scrapy.

```
import traceback
try:
 .... spider ...
except Exception as ex:
      traceback.print_exception(type(ex), ex, ex.__traceback__)
```

Comment: The code you've written here doesn't work, because of a syntax error. You cannot give positional arguments after you've given a keyword-argument, which is basically what you're doing. Looking at the [documentation for `LinkExtractor`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml) we can see this description of  the `deny` parameter: "deny (a regular expression (or list of))". Try giving it `[r'versicher', r'top', r'kredit']` instead and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Hi Hampus, I've tried this before. However, this results in an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_compile'.

Comment: Please update your question with the full stack-trace, and a reproducible example for us to work with. Right now, we don't have enough information to really pinpoint your problem.

Comment: The output from your "log" is not the full stack-trace. Nowhere in the output does it refer to any of you own calls, so we cannot know what list is causing the `AttributeError`.

Comment: I solved my problem. I deleted the rule lines and added them from scratch. Now everything works as expected....